# java socket programming chat

Tags: java, sockets

I'm Playing with a simple `Client` and `Server` application using socket, and i attempt to print a message in the console and get a response from the server but nothing shows up, i'm fairly new to sockets so i assume i have a logical error. It's a simple app that i want the client to prompt a user a user for a command (in my case an input string where the server will perform an action based on the `'th`character), send it to the server and just display the server response.I'm pretty sure my client isn't correct, can someone points out why i can't write anything from the client console.

```
 package socketProgramming;
        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;

 public class MyClient {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Socket socket= new Socket(); 
            BufferedReader in = null;
            String msg;
            int port = 2222;

            try {

                System.out.println("CLient wants to connect on port: "+port);

                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), port);
                System.out.println("The client is connected");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("connect failed");
                        System.exit(1);
            }

            try{
                 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                  String text = null;
            output.print(text);

            while ((text = input.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Client "+text);

            }


                socket.close();
                System.out.println("Client Exiting");
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }}


        }

package socketProgramming;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;



public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String msg = "";
        ServerSocket sSocket = null;
        Socket clientSocket;
        int port = 2222;//Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        try{
            sSocket = new ServerSocket(port);   

        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        while(true){
            try {// listen for a connection from client and accept it.
                System.out.println("Server is listenning on host: "
                        +InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() +""
                                + " and on port: "                  
                                + port);

                clientSocket = sSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection accepted");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

               // PrintWriter out =
                       // new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                PrintStream output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                msg = input.readLine();
                if(msg != null){
                    if(msg.charAt(12)=='4'){

                        System.out.println("reading message "+msg+" ");
                        output.print("Bye");
                        sSocket.close();
                        System.out.println("Server exits");
                    }else{
                        if(msg.charAt(12)=='0'){

                            System.out.println("reading message "+msg+" ");
                            output.print("OK");
                        }else if (msg.charAt(12)=='1'){

                            System.out.println("reading message "+msg+" ");

                            //Should return IP address
                            output.print(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                        }else if (msg.charAt(12)=='2'){

                            System.out.println("reading message "+msg+" ");
                            for(int i = 1; i<=10; ++i){

                                output.print(i);
                                output.print(" ");
                                }

                            }else if (msg.charAt(12)=='3'){


                                System.out.println("reading message "+msg+" ");
                                output.print("GOT IT");


                            }else{
                                System.out.println("*******************");
                            }

                        }



                    }
                    sSocket.close();
                    System.out.println("Server exits");
                }



            catch(IOException e) {
               System.out.println("accept failed");
               System.exit(1);
            }

        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }


    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate who is suppose to start the message and how?

Comment: If he client send something like `CCCCCCCC type0 4567322 X` since the `12th` char is 0 print `Bye` or anything. hope it's a little more clear

Comment: Well, I believe I found the answer to the socket problem. You may still have issues because printing a `null` string results in a `"null"` string, but hopefully you diagnose any further problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took some liberties with your code and changed it a bit.  It is by no means a perfect version of what you've supplied; however, it should get you pointed in the right direction.  These were the problems that were solved:

- MyClient was never prompting for user input.
- MyServer was sending strings without newlines.  MyClient was expecting strings with newlines.
- In MyServer, the main socket was being closed at the bottom of the loop.  I believe you intended to close the client socket so that the server would loop around and process another client.
- In MyServer, you're checking the 13th character of the user's input (because you were indexing the 12th byte (zero based) of the string.  I put in brute-force protection against checking the 13th byte of strings that are too short.
- Again, I simply corrected certain problems in your code.  I may have altered it beyond what your true goals actually are.  These examples are intended to get you going on your way...

MyClient.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyClient {

  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    int port = 2222;

    try {

      System.out.println("CLient wants to connect on port: " + port);

      socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), port);
      System.out.println("The client is connected");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("connect failed");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      PrintStream output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

      // Get a line of input from the user.
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String inputFromUser = br.readLine();

      // Send that line of input to MyServer.
      output.println(inputFromUser);

      // Print out the response from MyServer.
      System.out.println("SERVER RESPONSE: " + input.readLine());

      socket.close();
      System.out.println("Client Exiting");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

}
```

MyServer.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String msg = "";
    ServerSocket sSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket;
    int port = 2222;// Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    try {
      sSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (true) {
      try {// listen for a connection from client and accept it.
        System.out.println("Server is listenning on host: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "" + " and on port: "
            + port);

        clientSocket = sSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection accepted");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        // PrintWriter out =
        // new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        msg = input.readLine();
        if (msg != null) {
          if (msg.length() > 12 && msg.charAt(12) == '4') {

            System.out.println("reading message " + msg + " ");
            output.println("Bye");
            System.out.println("Server exits");
          } else {
            if (msg.length() > 12 && msg.charAt(12) == '0') {

              System.out.println("reading message " + msg + " ");
              output.println("OK");
            } else if (msg.length() > 12 && msg.charAt(12) == '1') {

              System.out.println("reading message " + msg + " ");

              // Should return IP address
              output.println(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
            } else if (msg.length() > 12 && msg.charAt(12) == '2') {

              System.out.println("reading message " + msg + " ");
              for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {

                output.println(i + " ");
              }

            } else if (msg.length() > 12 && msg.charAt(12) == '3') {

              System.out.println("reading message " + msg + " ");
              output.println("GOT IT");

            } else {
              System.out.println("*******************");

              // Invalid question from client, I guess.
              output.println("HUH?");
            }

          }

          // Make sure output is flushed to client.  It will be, but
          // just in case...
          output.flush();
        }

        // We're done with this client.  Close his socket.
        clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
        clientSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Closed client socket");
      }

      catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("accept failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
      }

      System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that nobody is actually sending any lines. This is what your client does:

```
output.print(text); //sends null
while ((text = input.readLine()) != null){ //waits to receive a line
```

This last part is where your client stops because it waits for input that the server never sends. So here is where the server stops:

```
msg = input.readLine(); //waits to recieve a line
```

It never reads in `null` because you didn't send a line (e.g. ending with `'\n'`). You can easily fix this problem by replacing your `output.print()` calls with `output.println()` calls, so that your readers know the line has end and can be read in now.